# Is self homotopy equivalence close to self homeomorphism?

Tags: general-topology, homotopy-theory, low-dimensional-topology

It is [known](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4097945/every-homotopy-equivalence-of-closed-surface-is-homotopic-to-a-homeomorphism) that *self homotopy equivalence of closed surfaces is homotopic to a self homeomorphism*. I wonder whether this statement holds for all closed manifolds. Note that no smoothness of the self homeomorphism is required.

I suspect this statement would fail in a low dimension. A potential conterexample is the map $X \times Y \xrightarrow{f \times g} Y \times X \xrightarrow{\sigma} X \times Y$, where $f: X \rightarrow Y$ and $g: Y \rightarrow X$ are homotopy equivalences between two closed manifolds (e.g. $L(7,1)$ and $L(7,2)$), and $\sigma: Y \times X \rightarrow X \times Y$ is the exchange map. Is this example valid? And what is the greatest dimension such that this statement still holds true?

Comment: According to the answer by Moishe Kohan, there is some theory in simple homotopy theory that is related to this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are **self-homotopy equivalences** of some 3-dimensional lens spaces (specifically, $L(12,1)$) which are not homotopic to self-homeomorphisms:

Darryl McCullough. "Mappings of reducible 3-manifolds." Banach Center Publications 18 (1986), p. 61-76.